# jQuery UI Autocomplete bug with ie9 in ASP.MVC3 View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.11 in a ASP.MVC3 web app.

In the view, I have the following javascript code:

```
 $("#textUsername" + UserNameCounter).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var params = {
                q: 5,
                term: request.term
            };
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(params, null, 2);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUsernames", "Controller")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This works neat in Chrome and FF, but it behavies strangely in IE9: 
when I start typing words and while autocomplete is showing the results it just deletes the results and the focus in the textbox is lost..

While googling around I realized that this pluging should work in IE9, and that most of the problems peeps post on forums are quite different from mine and are mostly related to syntax errors or something alike. Does anyone have any idea why the plugin is behaving like this on the view I'm working on?

Thanks in advanced.